# Microsoft Report Viewer: La definición del informe '' no es válida

Tags: reportviewer, mvvm

estoy trabajando por primera vez con Report viewer para RDLC reports en un ERP en MVVM. El caso es que a nadie de mi equipo le funciona en local la generación de informes menos a una persona. Ejecutando su código en mi máquina me funciona bien mientras que el mío no. He mirado todos los archivos del proyecto comparándolos y no veo diferencias pero alguna debe haber. Las versiones de las referencias de `Microsoft.Sqlserver.Types` y `Microsoft.Reportviewer` son las mismas. Y no hay referencias que tenga mi compañero que no tenga yo. El código es el mismo ya que trabajamos con control de versiones. La única diferencia que puede haber es un nuevo controller o un nuevo model correspondientes al desarrollo en curso pero nada más que yo haya detectado.

La excepción me salta en esta línea cuando voy a leer los parámetros del local report:

`ReportParameterInfoCollection pInfo = reportViewer.LocalReport.GetParameters();`

El mensaje de la excepción es `Se ha producido un error durante el procesamiento local de informes.`

La inner exception es:

Message:
`La definición del informe '' no es válida.`

Stack trace:

```
en Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   en Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(PreviewItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   en Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport()
   en Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Microsoft.Reporting.ILocalProcessingHost.CompileReport()
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
```

Source:
`Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common`

Source:
`Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`

Stacktrace:

```
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.GetParameters()
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.setParametersToLocalReport(ReportConfiguration conf, ReportViewer reportViewer) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs: línea 954
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GetReportViewerLocalProcessing(ReportConfiguration conf, ReportViewer reportViewer, Stream transformedTemplateStream) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs: línea 594
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateApplicationReport(ReportConfiguration conf) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs: línea 558
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateReportFromReportDefinition(ReportConfiguration conf, Document doc, PdfWriter PDFUnico) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs: línea 173
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateReport(ReportConfiguration conf, Document doc, PdfWriter PDFUnico) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs: línea 120
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateReport(List`1 configurations, Boolean PDFUnico) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs: línea 62
   en WimbiV2App.Controllers.DirectCustomerController.PrintInvoiceReports(Nullable`1 companyID, String factMode, Nullable`1 reportType, List`1 reportsSelected, List`1 invoiceToPrint, Nullable`1 visualized) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Controllers\DirectCustomerController.cs: línea 7040
```

Depurando el código que funciona y el que no funciona la única diferencia que encuentro antes del error es que en el proyecto que funciona LocalReport tiene HasExecutionSession a true mientras que el que no funciona lo tiene a false. El momento donde se pone a true es en la funcion `//Carga el fichero modificado reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(transformedTemplateStream);` A partir de ahí si quieres inspeccionar el objeto localReport te sale un mensaje como este:

[image: Mensaje de error al inpseccionar localReport]

No sé si puede ayudar este dato

Gracias de antemano.

La pila de la excepción entera:

```
System.Exception: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: Se ha producido un error durante el procesamiento local de informes. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: La definición del informe '' no es válida. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Error inesperado al procesar los informes. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(Object obj, Boolean verify, Boolean assertOnInvalidType)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.ExpressionInfo.Serialize(IntermediateFormatWriter writer)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(IPersistable persistableObj, Boolean verify)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.WriteVariantOrPersistable(Object obj)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.CreateHashForCachedDataSets()
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.InternalCreateIntermediateFormat(Stream definitionStream, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.CreateIntermediateFormat(Byte[] definition, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CompileOdpReport(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, String& reportDescription, String& reportLanguage, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext)
   en Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   en Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(PreviewItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   en Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport()
   en Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Microsoft.Reporting.ILocalProcessingHost.CompileReport()
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.GetParameters()
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.setParametersToLocalReport(ReportConfiguration conf, ReportViewer reportViewer) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 954
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GetReportViewerLocalProcessing(ReportConfiguration conf, ReportViewer reportViewer, Stream transformedTemplateStream) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 594
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateApplicationReport(ReportConfiguration conf) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 558
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateReportFromReportDefinition(ReportConfiguration conf, Document doc, PdfWriter PDFUnico) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 173
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateReport(ReportConfiguration conf, Document doc, PdfWriter PDFUnico) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 120
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateReport(List`1 configurations, Boolean PDFUnico) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 62
   en WimbiV2App.Controllers.DirectCustomerController.PrintInvoiceReports(Nullable`1 companyID, String factMode, Nullable`1 reportType, List`1 reportsSelected, List`1 invoiceToPrint, Nullable`1 visualized) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Controllers\DirectCustomerController.cs:línea 7040 ---> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: Se ha producido un error durante el procesamiento local de informes. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: La definición del informe '' no es válida. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Error inesperado al procesar los informes. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(Object obj, Boolean verify, Boolean assertOnInvalidType)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.ExpressionInfo.Serialize(IntermediateFormatWriter writer)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(IPersistable persistableObj, Boolean verify)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.WriteVariantOrPersistable(Object obj)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.CreateHashForCachedDataSets()
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.InternalCreateIntermediateFormat(Stream definitionStream, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.CreateIntermediateFormat(Byte[] definition, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CompileOdpReport(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, String& reportDescription, String& reportLanguage, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext)
   en Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   en Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(PreviewItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   en Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport()
   en Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Microsoft.Reporting.ILocalProcessingHost.CompileReport()
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.GetParameters()
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.setParametersToLocalReport(ReportConfiguration conf, ReportViewer reportViewer) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 954
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GetReportViewerLocalProcessing(ReportConfiguration conf, ReportViewer reportViewer, Stream transformedTemplateStream) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 594
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateApplicationReport(ReportConfiguration conf) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 558
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateReportFromReportDefinition(ReportConfiguration conf, Document doc, PdfWriter PDFUnico) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 173
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateReport(ReportConfiguration conf, Document doc, PdfWriter PDFUnico) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 120
   en WimbiV2App.Helpers.ReportGenerator.GenerateReport(List`1 configurations, Boolean PDFUnico) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Helpers\ReportGenerator.cs:línea 62
   en WimbiV2App.Controllers.DirectCustomerController.PrintInvoiceReports(Nullable`1 companyID, String factMode, Nullable`1 reportType, List`1 reportsSelected, List`1 invoiceToPrint, Nullable`1 visualized) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Controllers\DirectCustomerController.cs:línea 7040
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en WimbiV2App.Controllers.DirectCustomerController.PrintInvoiceReports(Nullable`1 companyID, String factMode, Nullable`1 reportType, List`1 reportsSelected, List`1 invoiceToPrint, Nullable`1 visualized) en C:\Users\pandres\Desktop\Atlas\pas2 - copia (2)\DEV-3-WimbiV2App\WimbiV2App\Controllers\DirectCustomerController.cs:línea 7069
```

Comment: Ya he conseguido solucionar el problema. En uno de los proyectos de la solución faltaba la dll Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he conseguido solucionar el problema. En uno de los proyectos de la solución faltaba la dll `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`